# Change element style based on another element's style without javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, flexbox

In CSS we have @media rule to change element's style based on conditions of window.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

But are there any ways to change element style based on another element's style WITHOUT USING JAVASCRIPT?

Example:

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  width: 100%
}

.div1 {
  color: #000000 when parent's width >= 400px;
  color: #FFFFFF when parent's width < 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make element styles relative to the parent element like this:

*SCSS:*

```
.parent {
    width: 100%
    & > .div1 { color: #FFFFFF; }
    @media (min-width 400px) {
        & > .div1 { color: #000000; }
    }
}
```

*CSS:*

```
.parent > div1 { color: #FFFFFF; }
@media (min-width 400px) {
    .parent > div1 { color: #000000; }
}
```